# WinJS error handlers not handling error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, winjs

Here's the MSDN documentation for `StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync`

> storageItemMostRecentlyUsedList.getFileAsync(token, options).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );

However, the following block of code throws an error for me which is not handled.

```
Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.mostRecentlyUsedList
.getFileAsync("invalid_token")
.done(
    function (file) {
        console.error("got file", file);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.error("silent error", error);
    }
);
```

Here's the error

[image]

If the token is legit, but the file has moved or been deleted, the error is not the same, also goes unhandled.

From [what I've read](http://sellsbrothers.com/12717), `done()` should throw an error, but `then()` should fail silently, allowing me to handle it myself. However, if I replace my `done()` with `then()` the result is exactly the same

I can just wrap the whole thing in a try / catch statement and handle my errors there, but what is the point of having an error handler func in the first place if it can't catch any errors?

Comment: u're missing name of function ... e.g. `sthAsync.done(function error(obj){console.log("bla bla")}, function success(obj){})`

Comment: nope, no effect. still throws an error